# How to hide a text value in RDFa?

Tags: html, schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool, rdfa

I want to hide the `name` of the publisher.

My code:

```html
<article typeof="NewsArticle">

  <h2 property="headline">Wie instaliert Virtual Box in Windows 10</h2>

  <meta img property="image" src="Bilder/me.png">

  <span property="name" value="Virtual Box"/>
  <span property="mainEntityOfPage" value="http://google.de"/>
  <span property="datePublished" value="2019-03-07"/>
  <span property="dateModified" value="2019-03-17"/>
  <span property="publisher" typeof="Organization">
     <span property="name">http://htmlkurss.xyz</span>
     <span property="logo" typeof="ImageObject">
       <meta img property="contentUrl url" src="/index.php/Bild /Virtualbox.png" alt="VirtualBox" />
     </span>
  </span>

  <p property="articleBody">Virtual Box ist eine Virtualisierungssoftware, die viele Betriebessysteme emulieren kann. Sie funktioniert mit Linux , Mac und Windows. Sie hat auch veschiedenene Sprachen für ihre Oberfläche, wie beispielsweise Deutsch, Englisch ,... 
  </p>

  <p property="author" typeof="Person">Autor: <span 
  property="name">http://htmlkurss.xyz</span></p>

  <p>Korrekturen: <span property="editor">Rolf B</span></p>
</article>
```

I have tried:

```html
<meta property="publisher" typeof="Organization">
<span property="name">http://htmlkurss.xyz</>
```

Google's Structured Data Testing Tool is warning me that Logo and Name must write.

Comment: Your logo (`ImageObject`) doesn’t have a name. The publisher (`Organization`) has a name. Do you want to hide the name of the publisher?

Comment: yes , i want to hide  the name , "http://htmlkurss.xyz" , now it display http://htmlkurss.xyz/windows8.php , and very Thanks because my Question your translate...

Comment: Note that you have many errors in your HTML. I already explained in your other questions that `span` can’t have a `value` attribute. And `<meta img` is wrong, too. I would recommend to validate your HTML: https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t want to display a text value in HTML+RDFa, you can use the `meta` element:

```html
<span property="name">Alice</span>
```

becomes

```html
<meta property="name" content="Alice" />
```

Comment: Veryyyyyyyy Thanks , i to do it.. "<meta property="name" content="http://htmlkurss.xyz"/>" and now not to come the Warning .